# Facebook api autopost

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i use facebook api for auto post from my website.
here is my code, after that i explain my problem:

```
require_once "Facebook/autoload.php";
        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
            'app_id' => 'xxxxxxx',
            'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2'
        ]);
$pageAccessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

        $linkData = [
            'link' => $link,
            'message' => $message,
            'picture' => $pic
        ];

        try {
            $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

my problem is that, this code work sometimes, not all time.
and in sometime i see these errors:

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 1
Filename: Http/GraphRawResponse.php
Line Number: 108
```

and

```
Severity: 4096
Message: Argument 4 passed to Facebook\FacebookResponse::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/deponews/public_html/application/controllers/Facebook/FacebookClient.php on line 225 and defined
Filename: Facebook/FacebookResponse.php
Line Number: 75
```

i go to api explorer , and select my page from drop down and at the bottom drop down , select access page token , then select my page name again.
and copy generation token into my page access token.

i don't know why sometimes this code work well , and sometimes its not.

any idea ?

tnx

Comment: You are only catching two specific exceptions - make sure to catch general ones as well, so that you don't miss any error the API might report.

Comment: @CBroe, actually i use API doc , to write this code, this code exactly what day say...

Comment: That doesn't mean that it covers all possibilities. Those are _basic_ examples. When stuff doesn't work, it is up to you to take the necessary steps to find out why. So start by doing what I said please.